# Cambiar fondo de algunas celdas grid con tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo una tabla en una ventana y tengo dos problemas con el encabezado.

El primero es que quiero que el *encabezado tenga color*, pero claro, yo lo que he hecho es darle color de fondo al texto, pero eso no me sirve porque en los datos de la tabla, si el texto es muy largo, la *celda* se ensancha y entonces queda el texto con fondo pero el resto de la celda no. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

El segundo es que para colocar los *label* de cada *celda* en lugar de ponerlos uno a uno decidí meter los nombres en una lista y colocar cada elemento de esa lista en la cabecera. El problema viene en que si los nombres de la lista tienen tildes me salta error, en cambio si no tienen tildes me sale bien, pero no entiendo por qué sucede esto ya que cuando hago los *labels* uno a uno, aunque el texto tenga tildes me sale bien. ¿Alguna idea?

Adjunto el código con el que formo el encabezado.
Donde *claves* es la lista de nombres.

```
for i in range(len(cabecera)):
    cabecera = Label(consultas,text=claves[i], font=("Cambria",11),padx=10)
    cabecera .grid(row=0,column=i, sticky="n")
    cabecera .config(bg="light sky blue")
```

> **P.D.:** Cabe destacar que como he dicho el código en sí funciona bien, solo falla cuando tengo tildes en las palabras de la lista.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

El problema del color de fondo está en:

```
cabecera.grid(row=0,column=i, sticky="n")
```

en concreto en el valor del argumento `sticky`. Con `"n"` (*north*) se le está indicando al *Label* que se "pegue" al borde superior del espacio disponible en su celda de la rejilla, sin más.

El tamaño del Label por defecto será el mínimo necesario para contener su texto, por lo tanto, no es el color de fondo solo se aplique al texto (`background` se aplica a todo el *Label*), es que ese es el tamaño del widget.

Esto obviamente nos da como resultado cosas como:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La solución es obligar al widget a ocupar todo el espacio disponible usando `sticky="nswe"`, esto le indica que debe "pegarse a los cuatro bordes de la celda", por tanto expandiéndose lo necesario para ocupar todo el espacio del que dispone.

Un ejemplo:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Tabla(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        tabla = {
            "Cabecera 1": [
                "Lorem ipsum",
                "consectetur adipiscing elit"],
            "Cabecera 2": [
                "dolor sit amet", 
                "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt"]
            }

        for col, (cabecera, filas) in enumerate(tabla.items()):
            label_cabecera = tk.Label(
                self,
                text=cabecera,
                bg="light sky blue",
                borderwidth=1,
                relief="solid",
            )
            label_cabecera.grid(row=0, column=col, sticky="nswe") 
            for row, fila in enumerate(filas):
                label_fila = tk.Label(
                    self,
                    text=fila,
                    background="Khaki",
                    borderwidth=1,
                    relief="solid",
                    ) 
                label_fila.grid(row=row + 1, column=col, sticky="nswe")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Tabla")
    Tabla(root).pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

y el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Nota

En cuanto al segundo problema, falta la información mínima en la pregunta para poder abordarlo (como la excepción concreta, versión de tkinter/tcl/tk), de hecho no se me ocurre siquiera una forma de reproducirlo actualmente.